# Convert JSON Data To DataTable

Tags: c#, json

I am hitting api endpoint that returns a json string.  I need to take that json string and populate a C# DATATABLE.  How is this achieved?

This is the code I have to get the JSON...

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DTL()
{
    var data = _context.TC.FromSqlRaw("Select * from employeeInfo order by employeeID Asc").ToList();

    //I need data converted to a DataTable C#
}
```

How do this happen with C# code?

**EDIT**

This is what my JSON data returned looks like:

```
{"data":[{"empName": "Jason", "empManager": "Richard", "userID": "ja123"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install NewtonSoft json from Nuget package manager

Then add this in your Namespace

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.DataSet>(data.ToString());
```

---

**EDIT:**

Identifier data was of type object, converted it to String and was sorted

Comment: I get build errors of - Argument 1 can not convert from System.Data.DataTable to string, Argument 2 can not convert from System.Type to Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings

Comment: Or you could use `var dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);`

Comment: @HotTomales, thats because the json should be of type object or you can use Generic as suggested by stuartd

Comment: @stuartd - I get an error of can not convert from Generic.List<empInfo> to string

Comment: @Clint - I have that package installed and I copied your syntax

Comment: @stuartd: Is your json string a collection ? if yes, then use
`var dt =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DataTable>>(json);`

Comment: @Clint - it is a json string.  if I try the above syntax I get the same error can not convert from Generic.List<empInfo> to string

Comment: @HotTomales: In your code what type is `var data` and can you share sample value that it holds

Comment: @Clint - I posted a sample of what the data I am expecting to convert to datatable looks like. --- see my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204621/discussion-between-clint-and-hottomales).